# How to skip empty field from API using .map() function in Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a custom repository API, I want to showcase it in my `Next.js` web app. But if an empty field is found in the API, I want to skip that element.

***My API:***

```
{
    "myrepo": [
        {
            "name": "Lorem Ipsum 1",
            "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
            "language": "TypeScript",
            "html_link": "https://example.com/project1",
            "homepage": "https://projectdomain1.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Lorem Ipsum 2",
            "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
            "language": "JavaScript",
            "html_link": "https://example.com/project2",
            "homepage": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Lorem Ipsum 3",
            "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
            "language": "C#",
            "html_link": "https://example.com/project3",
            "homepage": "https://projectdomain3.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

***ProjectCard.tsx***

```
import useSWR from 'swr';

import fetcher from 'lib/fetcher';
import type { Repos } from 'lib/types';

export default function ProjectsCard() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR<Repos>('/api/repo', fetcher);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Failed to load</div>;
  }
  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {data.myrepo.map((repo, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="mb-8">
          <p className="text-gray-900 font-medium">
            1. Project Name: {repo.name}
          </p>

          <p className="text-gray-900 font-medium">
            2. Project Description: {repo.description}
          </p>

          <p className="text-gray-900 font-medium">
            3. Project Link: {repo.html_url}
          </p>

          {repo.homepage !== '' && (
            <p className="text-gray-900 font-medium">
              4. Project Homepage: {repo.homepage}
            </p>
          )}

          <p className="text-gray-900 font-medium">
            5. Project Language: {repo.language}
          </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

`4. Project Homepage:` not hide for 2nd child.
I want to completely remove the `4. Project Homepage:` element if homepage return blank.

I want the final output look like this:

`For 1st`

1 Project Name: ....

2 Project Description: ....

3 Project Link: ....

4 Project Homepage: ....

5 Project Language: ....

`For 2nd (Check it, No. 4 is not here)`

1 Project Name: ....

2 Project Description: ....

3 Project Link: ....

5 Project Language: ....

`For 3rd`

1 Project Name: ....

2 Project Description: ....

3 Project Link: ....

4 Project Homepage: ....

5 Project Language: ....

Comment: [`.filter(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check length of string:

```
repo.homepage !== '' 
&& repo.homepage != undefined 
&& repo.homepage?.length < 1 && (
   // other code is omitted for th ebrevity
```

Comment: I am getting an error.

Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')

Comment: @SayanDey please, see my updated answer